# How to store application data in the google play store

Tags: android, mobile, xamarin.android, google-play

I'm a bit new to Android development in general.

Problem:
My problem is that of scalability and security. I need to write a fairly straight forward data lookup application where the user has to pay for various sets of reference data which they can view on their mobile device offline. I am aware of how to create product references in the Google Play Store and validate the user has purchased X set(s) of data. However, I'd rather not package the entire database of reference material with the application. It seems logical that the application would download purchased data sets locally  (or to the user's Google Drive APP Folder) upon purchase validation.

Question:
Is there a way to store application data sets in the play store that are NOT user specific and not downloaded to the device automatically when the app is installed? Or, is this a scenario that I would have to create my own cloud hosted service which accepts data requests upon purchase validation? Another option / best practice for this scenario that would not involve a 3rd party hosted service?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with expansion files.  Generally you'd combine that with in app purchases, although you could do it based off some other factor.  See https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html  and look at the section on using the Downloader Library.

Answer (score 2):

You are not able to store datasets in the Play Store that won't be downloaded with every app download. However, Google Cloud Platform has the tools to allow you to do this:

1. Create a backend for your app on Google App Engine
2. Store the data in datastore or google cloud storage
3. Create an in-app purchase for particular datasets
4. Use App Engine Endpoints to create a servlet that will deliver the data to the app when the in-app purchase has been made

You should be able to do all this from within Android Studio and basically for free.